# Should I use "nor" or "or" in this specific sentence?

Tags: or-nor

I am writing a manuscript. There is a sentence my advisor and I keep editing.

The sentence:

> We did not detect significant effects of lineage, initial length, nor status on individual growth rate.

Would it be more appropriate to write the above sentence with "or" instead of "nor"? If so, why? And why do I have to use "or?

Comment: Usually, *nor* goes with *neither*. No neither, no nor. Poetically, I might use "We detected no X, nor Y, nor Z." But that's a high tone, even above acedemia.